# How to set filename while writing in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm saving a dataframe to csv with the following code:

```
df.write\
    .option("header",True) \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .option("sep","|")\
    .format("csv") \
    .save("filepath")
```

This saves the file as *part-xxx-xx.csv*

I want to save the file as *Tablename.csv*. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have option to give filename when writing files in spark because of partitioning but you can use Hadoop Filesystem API to rename your partition.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}

fs = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)

partCSV=new Path("/your-path-here/part-xxx-xx.csv")
tablenameCSV= new Path("/your-path-here/Tablename.csv")

//Rename a File
fs.rename(partCSV,tablenameCSV)
```

see: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-rename-and-delete-file-directory-from-hdfs/

Comment: What your solution does is it creates a Tablename folder and inside that folder the csv files are saved as part-xxx-xx.csv. I need the csv file itself to be named as Tablename.csv